# Configure HttpClient to use a service to populate the authentication header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to use a [typed HTTP client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) so I register it like this in the `ServiceCollection`

```
services.AddHttpClient<ApiService>();
```

All the requests that the client makes, must be authenticated. So I'd need to slightly modify the snippet above to this:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ApiService>(c =>
{
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "");
});
```

The bearer token needs to be renewed all 5 minutes, so I need to create service that needs dependencies like an HttpClient (to authenticate and get the token) and a MemoryCache (to store the token as long it's valid).

The problem is, as you can see, this is still in the phase before the service provider is built, so I can't resolve anything at this point... What are my options here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the ServiceProvider like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ApiService>(provider, c) =>
{
    var token = provider.GetRequiredService<MyTokenService>().GetToken();
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
});
```

If you **don't** have access to the overload with the provider you will need to update your dependencies.
`AddHttpClient` will register a transient client so the func ("factory method") will run each time you inject it somewhere.

Comment: uuh perfect, I didn't see this

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this in the constructor of `ApiService`, also passing the authentication service to that via DI?

e.g.

```cs
public class ApiService
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public ApiService(HttpClient client, IAuthenticationService auth)
    {
        // configure client here

        this.client = client;
    }
}
```